# Getting a Visual studio error in a <ItemTemplate> string

Tags: c#, asp.net

The project compiles fine but Visual Studio complains with a error.

> Error 3   ) expected

Visual studio wants me to put a ) between the i and g in ImageSmallHeight

```
<img 
runat = "server" 
Visible ='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("PictureFilename").ToString())%>'
width='<%#ImageSmallWidth %>' 
height='<%#ImageSmallHeight %>'
border="0" 
alt="" 
src='<%# "/images/archive/{0}?crop=auto&amp;width={1}&height={2}".AsFormatString(Eval("PictureFilename"),ImageSmallWidth,ImageSmallHeight)%>' />
```

drives me nuts not understanding why. Anyone that have seen this?

Comment: why are you doing this in your from end/ASPX? you really should do things like this on the codebehind

Comment: @Ahmedilyas i agrea, its a old project i inherited.

Comment: sure. in which case you can easily convert it to code behind and bind the data through that way

Answer (score 2):

If you re-format slightly it should be ok:

```
    <img 
runat = "server" 
Visible ='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("PictureFilename").ToString())%>'
width='<%#ImageSmallWidth %>' 
height='<%#ImageSmallHeight %>'
border="0" 
alt="" 
src='<%# String.Format("/images/archive/{0}?crop=auto&amp;width={1}&height={2}", Eval("PictureFilename"), ImageSmallWidth,ImageSmallHeight )  %>' />
```

I changed to use String.Format and things look to compile ok. My guess is something's weird with that AsFormatString method.